# Magento - Add root category link to the menu

Tags: php, magento

I am new to Magento and I don't know how to link the root category to the menu. 
It seems that there is no option for this in the backend.

Any idea on how to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: For clarity: root categories are never displayed in the frontend. They have two functions: collecting all top-level categories for a scope and association with a scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Category under the root category and put all category there in.

Comment: I was thinking about this approach also but any other direct approach ?

Comment: What do you mean by direct approach? There are no options in Magento admin to do. If you don't want to modify the code.

Comment: what I mean is that "other approach". Any guide on how to implement this by modifying the code ?

Comment: If you are new to magento don't think about changing base functionality. Everything is great if you add a node as your root category

Answer (score 0):

$rootcategory_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
$collection = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')->load($rootcategory_id);
$rootcaturl= $collection->getUrl();//**default category url** i.e *root category of the store*